# I get a pygame error for 'pygame.mixer.music.play'

Tags: python, pygame, mixer

I get this error and I don't know why. I am using Visual Studio Code:

pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=-1, start=0.0, fade_ms=4000)
TypeError: function takes at most 2 keyword arguments (3 given)

I have this code in a part of my game:

```
pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join("assets", "game_music.wav"))
pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=-1, start=0.0, fade_ms=4000)
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.3)
```

I also have:

```
import pygame
import os
from pygame import mixer

pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 512)
mixer.init()
pygame.init()
```

I want to have all 3 arguments.
It should work according to https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.play
Can someone help me please?

Comment: From the documentation `Changed in pygame 2.0.0: Added optional fade_ms argument`, which version of pygame do you use? If it's lower than 2.0.0 just remove the `fade_ms` argument

Comment: You can find your pygame version by running `pip show pygame` in the command line prompt.

Comment: Thank you!! I had to update my version of Pygame. fixed and running well now